# 'ambiguous implicit values' when injecting two actors into Play controller

Tags: scala, dependency-injection, playframework, akka, guice

I want to inject two actors into a Play controller via DI. Injecting one actors works absolutely fine and I can send message to this actor without any problems. However, when injecting a second actor and sending a message, I get the following compilation error:

```
play.sbt.PlayExceptions$CompilationException: Compilation error[ambiguous implicit values:
 both value fooSupervisor in class MyController of type akka.actor.ActorRef
 and value barSupervisor in class MyController of type akka.actor.ActorRef
 match expected type akka.actor.ActorRef]
```

My controller looks like this:

```
class MyController @Inject()(
                                           implicit system: ActorSystem,
                                           materializer: Materializer,
                                           @Named("FooSupervisor") fooSupervisor: ActorRef,
                                           @Named("BarSupervisor") barSupervisor: ActorRef
                                         ) extends Controller {


}
```

And the module looks as follows:

```
class Module extends AbstractModule with ScalaModule with AkkaGuiceSupport {

  def configure() {
    // ....
    bindActor[FooSupervisor]("FooSupervisor")
    bindActor[BarSupervisor]("BarSupervisor")
    ()
  }

}
```

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You define the two actors as implicit parameters. Change the signature like so:

```
class MyController @Inject()(
  @Named("FooSupervisor") fooSupervisor: ActorRef,
  @Named("BarSupervisor") barSupervisor: ActorRef
  )(implicit system: ActorSystem, materializer: Materializer
  ) extends Controller {
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried injecting the actorRef into the controller from a provider.

```
import javax.inject._
import akka.actor.ActorRef
import play.api.mvc._

@Singleton
class HomeController @Inject()(@Named("actor1") val actor1: ActorRef, @Named("actor2") val actor2: ActorRef) extends Controller {
  def index = Action {
    actor1 ! "hello actor1"
    actor2 ! "hello actor2"
    Ok("Hello")
  }
}
```

The Module should bind the actorRef.

```
import javax.inject.{Inject, Provider}
import com.google.inject.AbstractModule
import net.codingwell.scalaguice.ScalaModule
import actors.{Actor1, Actor2}
import akka.actor.{ActorRef, ActorSystem, Props}

class Module extends AbstractModule with ScalaModule{
  override def configure() = {
    bind[ActorRef].annotatedWithName("actor1").toProvider[Actor1Provider]
    bind[ActorRef].annotatedWithName("actor2").toProvider[Actor2Provider]
  }
}

class Actor1Provider @Inject() (system: ActorSystem) extends Provider[ActorRef]{
  override def get(): ActorRef = system.actorOf(Props[Actor1])
}

class Actor2Provider @Inject() (system: ActorSystem) extends Provider[ActorRef]{
  override def get(): ActorRef = system.actorOf(Props[Actor2])
}
```

If you need a materializer and actorSystem please pass them as implicit parameters. Since we have injected the actorRef itself, we might not need a actorSystem to interact with the actors. But depending upon what else you do inside the controller - if you need things like materializer or actorSystem making them implicit is better.